# Validate Each Column of dataTable using HashTable

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I have a datatable whose columns are lets say col1,col2,col3
Now I want to validate each column value whether its 0 or not

I do not want to use if else clause that will be writing to much stuff.

Is there any possibility to do the same task using HashTable or something else ?

Comment: No else clause: very strange requirement to have. Why?

Comment: That's an Order and I have to obey it

Comment: An order to not use `else` in programming? Whats the reason for such an order??

Comment: Well u never know what goes on in boss' mind

Comment: What do you want to do with this validation?

Comment: I would ask that boss to give an explanation for such a demand...

Comment: If your boss is making such silly demands either get a new boss, or make use of the conditional operator.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the `Columns` and store the columns which have value 0 in a `List<DataColumn>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an event handler for the OnColumnChanged Event and check that the value is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if any column is 0, then:

```
bool haveZero = (col1 == 0) || (col2 == 0) || (col3 == 0)
```

if you need to know if all are zero, then replace ors with ands.

If you are trying to work out if any value in a column is zero, then you can use LINQ:

bool col1HasZero = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Rows.Select(r => (int)r.[1]).Any(v => v == 0);

and replace Any(predicate) by All(predicate) to see if all the values are zero.

(Link against System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll for LINQ to DataSets).